# Unable to navigate to URL due to authentication issue

Tags: python, python-requests

I am new to writing Python programs and have had no prior experience with automating user tasks on a website, so apologies if I've overlooked the obvious.

What I'm trying to do, is automate a file download from an intranet site. There's no specific URL as it's a javascript site, so my thinking is to automate the user steps to download the file, i.e. 1) login to site 2) navigate to the 'reporting' link 3) open and submit the form that creates the report.

I've found myself stuck in a loop when trying to login to the site. If I navigate to the login page ".../example.asp/login/default.asp" I receive an error "Unauthorised: invalid credentials error". Interestingly, if I try navigating directly to the reporting link, I am sent to the timeout page "your session has expired click *here* to login" - *here* redirecting me back to the login/default.asp page.

Any ideas how I can get past this issue is greatly appreciated!

Here is the basic code I've been working with:

```
import requests
from requests import session




url = 'http://example.com/example_asp/login/default.asp'

 payload = {
'username': 'UID',
'password': 'PWD'
}

with session() as c:   
 request = c.get(url, payload)

print(request.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deal with authentication issues, I used my Chrome browser cookies with this script: http://n8henrie.com/2014/05/decrypt-chrome-cookies-with-python/

Makes everything pretty simple:

```
url = 'http://www.example.com'
s = requests.Session()
cookies = pyCookieCheat.chrome_cookies(url)
s.get(url, cookies = cookies)
```